# Requesting an API key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, api-key

I'm requesting an API key from [this site](http://www.footytube.com/openfooty/signup.php) and they are asking me for two things I'm not totally clear (Disregard the fact that if I don't know how to answer these questions I shouldn't be requesting an API key)on.

**1. IP access** ["Enter the IP Adresses that will be accessing the service"](http://www.footytube.com/openfooty/signup.php)

I ran 'host "www.myapp.com"' in the terminal to get a list of IP's are these the adressess I put in this field?

**2. User Agent** ["Enter a user agent string below for the purposes of id'in your application"](http://www.footytube.com/openfooty/signup.php)

How would I find this and how does this fit into the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the right idea with the host command, assuming www.myapp.com is where the requests will come from.  It says to put them into a comma-separated list, like this: `1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8, 9.10.11.12`

The user-agent depends on what software is making the requests, so it depends on what you're using and you can often choose what to set it to.  You can learn more about user-agents on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)  If you happen to be using Nokogiri to make the request, you can choose your UA like this:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open(url, "User-Agent" => "MyApp"))
```

You might want to set it to something like `MyApp` that identifies you.